# How to remove table view cell when data get from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlXDm.png)I have made simple one user contact details app.
When user press button open new view fill the data it will stored that data on userDefault.

Now on my first view I get those data on my table view cell.

It is going perfectly.

Now i want to delete from the table view using SWIPE TO DELETE .
I can do this I am able to remove row from table view.

## My question is

How can I remove permanently from the user Default.
Because when I reload my app my previous row showing me again which I did swipe to delete.

Please answer me.

Tank you

## Images

[Swipe to delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlXDm.png)

[enter image description here][2]

[delete the data from first row]

Now i reload the data it displays again 
[enter image description here][3]

Comment: provide your code for more details

Comment: Set "nil"  nsuserdefaults
[testObject setValue:nil forKey:@"keyInteger"];

Comment: how you store data in user default? add those code

Comment: implement swipe functionality and update the `datasource` of your `tableView`.

Answer (score 0):

Before Delete, Please reset data which is present in your NSUserDefaults like

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:nil forKey:@"your_key_name"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

And Don't forgot last statement

Comment: *last statement* is not necessary. The operating system updates user defaults frequently.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that key from user default like this

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"yourKey"];
```

But when you came next time on that view make sure you are not again updating the data in your `NSUserDefault`, as after updating it, it will again show you the same data.